# Is there way to use SelectMany for Dictionary

Tags: c#

I'm currently query dictionary like below,

```
foreach (var instance in Dict)
{
   X += $"(Description = '{instance.Key}') OR ";
}
```

Can I use `SelectMany` and prepare string `X`. I also need to eliminate last `OR`?

```
Dict.SelectMany(p=>p.Key.....)
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs **and expected outputs based on those sample inputs**.

Comment: What are you generating, if not dynamic SQL? I ask since this feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `string.Join` and `Select`

```
var result = string.Join(" OR ",dict.Keys.Select(x=> $"Description = '{x}'"));
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/JPAIAw)

---

**Additional Resources**

[Dictionary.Keys Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keys?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Gets a collection containing the keys in the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

[String.Join Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a
>   collection, using the specified separator between each element or
>   member.

[Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

Answer (score 1):

mjwills asks an interesting question. If this is SQL then simplistically you can do:

```
var sql = "description IN ('" + string.Join("','". dict.Keys) + ")";
```

It would be better to do this though:

```
var sql = new SqlCommand(",,, description IN ('", connstr);
var p = 0;
foreach(string k in dict.Keys){
  sql.CommandText += $"@p{p},";
  sql.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@p{p++},", k);
}
sql.CommandText = sql.CommandText.TrimEnd(',') + ")";
```

There are some reasons to avoid using AddWithValue (google for "can we stop using addwithvalue already") but this demonstrates the general technique- we dynamically concatenate parameters names onto an sql and then add those parameters to a collection. This should always preferred over simple string concatenation

Other ways of passing arrays of values to databases exist, depending on the db vendor - if you're using sqlserver you could take a look at table valued parameters, for example